# Getting "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration" when accessing from subdomain

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The app I'm building is going to have multiple parts over various subdomains, i.e. front-end "domain.ca", and api would be "api.domain.ca".  In the facebook app settings we set the domain as "domain.ca", and the website url as "http://domain.ca", it says it would allow all subdomains access as well.

When I try to use the auth on "api.domain.ca", I get "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

How can I make this work?  We want the user to be able to use the login on the front side, and pass the access_token to the api side to check if the user exists, or create a new user and attach the social login.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Periklis Koutsogiannis who posted an answer to my question on the Facebook Developer Community page: "You may fill the Valid OAuth redirect URIs under Client OAuth Settings in Settings/Advanced."  This solved the issue.